# Swiper and current page index

Tags: javascript, html, swipe, html-framework-7, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper API](https://swiperjs.com/api/) to let the user swipe across multiple pages on my HTML5/JS/CSS website.
I initialized the swiper (plase note I'm using Framework7 which includes Swiper API as an internal module, the `app` object represent the Framework7 instance:

```
var swiper = app.swiper.create('#swiper', {
    speed: 200,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    initialSlide: 0,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
    },
    autoHeight: true,
});
```

I also have three slides on my HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-container" id="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"> 
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I wrote a listener to listen for page changes: each time the user swipes to the next page, the `transitionEnd` event is fired

```
swiper.on("transitionEnd", function(e){
    var slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
    console.log("I'm on slide no: "+slideIndex);
});
```

When I try to retrieve the current slide index (`swiper.activeIndex`) I get very weird results: I would expect to get a number, either 0, 1 or 2 (the current page index).
If I don't wrap around I get 1,2,3 (ok, not 0-based, perfectly fine I'll add a -1). If I wrap around (Swiper seamlessly swipes in loop, wrapping around the pages) I also get 0, and 4 as indexes and I don't know why.

The documentation says that in loop mode (`loop: true`) the active page index works as follow:

> Index number of currently active slide
>
> Note, that in loop mode active index value will be always shifted on a
> number of looped/duplicated slides

Still don't understand that sentence. "shifted on a number of looped slides"?

Inspecting the HTML I can see that Swiper API creates extra "duplicates" slides at the far left and right of the "real" slide sequence, to create the effect of a seamless loop across pages.

But if effectively I just have 3 pages, why I also get indexes 0 and 4 instead of just 1,2,3? (page1 = 1, page2 = 2, page3 = 3)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With loop enabled, swiper duplicates the first slide to the end, and the last Slide before the first too keep the animation in flow.

3 Pages + 2 Duplicates = 5 Pages (index 0-4)

With `swiper.activeIndex` you are accessing the virtual slides, just use `swiper.realIndex` for the real index.